# 2nd GPU does nothing

Tags: gpu

I bought a new PC a few months ago and noticed that my 2nd GPU always is on 0% (I only saw it once on `Copy 1%` in the task manager, but further never again).

I would think this is not supposed to be like this, but why is it and how do I solve it.

Here are my computer details:

- Laptop: Lenovo E590
- GPU-0: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/details/n82y)
- GPU-1: Radeon (TM) RX 550X: (https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/details/wxvad)

If you need other details, feel free to ask.

Comment: The 2nd GPU will only kick in on 'harder tasks' such as 3D graphics e.g. Excel will use the on-chip Intel, but a game will fall over to the Radeon. Check whilst running something more demanding.

Comment: When I play games it just stays on the 1st, it goes to 99% and the other one stays at 0%.

Comment: What games? Have you looked in the settings for your GPU? There should be settings for what applications will run on it.

Comment: Planetside 2, Minecraft (yes this still exists) and Fallout mostly. I can't find the settings. I can, however, find the games (mc excluded) in the Radeon Settings gaming tab.